# Error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker." :how to update child entities correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have tried multiple solution found in stack and the internet i have lost a full day of work behind this please have a look to my code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(JobeezUserInfoViewModel jobeezUserInfo, HttpPostedFileBase UploadedImage)
    {
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        //list of languages
        var lgs = jobeezUserInfo.Languages.Select(l => l.LanguageId);

//Languages to be deleted
        var lngTodel = db.Languages.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(ut => ut.JobeezUserInfoId == jobeezUserInfo.ApplicationUserId)
            .Where(ut => !lgs.Contains(ut.LanguageId));
//language ids as Ilist for better performace
var ids = lgs as IList<int> ?? lgs.ToList();
//Languages to be added
        var lngToAdd = ids
            .Where(
                lid =>
                    user.JobeezUserInfo.Languages
                        .Select(ut => ut.LanguageId) //for each userlanguages create a list if languageids _
                        .Contains(lid) == false //_check if it does not contain the posted languageids and return the language ids if it is the case(tid is the posted languageid)
            )
            .Select(tid =>

                new Language()
                {

                    JobeezUserInfoId = user.Id,
                    LanguageId = tid,
                    Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Enums.LanguageEnum), tid)
                });
//languages to be updated
        var lngToUpdate = user.JobeezUserInfo.Languages.Where(l=>ids.Contains(l.LanguageId));


        Mapper.CreateMap<JobeezUserInfoViewModel, JobeezUserInfo>(MemberList.Destination);
        JobeezUserInfo info = Mapper.Map<JobeezUserInfo>(jobeezUserInfo) as JobeezUserInfo;

        user.FirstName = jobeezUserInfo.FirstName;
        user.LastName = jobeezUserInfo.LastName;
        user.PostCode = jobeezUserInfo.PostCode;
        user.PhoneNumber = jobeezUserInfo.Telephone;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //mark modified for the userinfo
            db.JobeezUserInfo.Attach(info); // Entity is in Unchanged state
            db.Entry(info).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

And the next line is this  - My question is why I cant attach the language object 'l'

```
lngToUpdate.ForEach(l =>
        {
            db.Languages.Attach(l);
            db.Entry(l).State = EntityState.Modified;

        });
```

I have the error

> "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker."

I have opened the  the quick view After the following line (one part of the image shows also the input parameters of my controler action (viewmodel object):

```
            //mark modified for the userinfo
            db.JobeezUserInfo.Attach(info); // Entity is in Unchanged state
```

[image]

Precision : the languageobject in the db.changetracket.Entities() is the same object that is posted to my server (in my viewModel) why the enitity framework cannot understand that the new object has to be tracked or attached in place of the new language object (My code is partial for the sake of clarity i can post full code if needed) 
My question is  : I really dont know what is the best method to update the child entities correctly. What am I doing wrong here and how to get this work ?
thanks in advance

Comment: You probably have to make `lngToUpdate` distinct.

Comment: it is really not cool to have downvoted without even explaining anything it is like what we might have qualified in France as - "c'est rat, mais et merci de votre gentillesse!" @GertArnold the list is distinct. whatever it crashes at the first iteration itself ! the problem is that the language list cant be attached because theEF is keeping track of the language list found in my viewModel thanks anyways! I dont know how i can replace this tracked object with my new list..? sometimes EF really difficult with some of it subtilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that I have two different errors actually

> 1.

I had this error because `lngToUpdate` was a wrongly populated one - speaking about the following line (my bad! ;) ).

```
var lngToUpdate = user.JobeezUserInfo.Languages.Where(l=>ids.Contains(l.LanguageId));
```

It is the same collection as in the database which was obviously already been tracked.
so I created a new collection with the modified property values for each languages who's properties were to be updated.

> 2.

Now For the other two lists  `lngToAdd` and `lngToUpdate` , with the `ObjectStateManager` gotten buy the following code

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
```

I used the manager to change the `objectState` of the peviously tracked languages as `EntityState.unchanged`, attched the new ones to the context and marked `EntityState.Added EntityState.Deleted` respectively (as per my lists).

and it worked! hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my parent child problem by using AsNoTracking().

Here BOND is my Parent table and  `GOVBONDINTERESTSCHEDULE` is its Child. Also FI is another child table of BOND. A simple update Threw an error because of EF tracking. So I simply updated `GOVBONDINTERESTSCHEDULE` using `AsNoTracking()`.

**Below is my working code.**

```
GOVBONDINTERESTSCHEDULE editmodel = new GOVBONDINTERESTSCHEDULE();
editmodel = new Entities(Session["Connection"] as EntityConnection).
    GOVBONDINTERESTSCHEDULEs.Include("BOND").AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.REFERENCE == Ref).
    SingleOrDefault();
editmodel.STATUS = ConstantVariable.STATUS_APPROVED;
editmodel.LASTUPDATED = DateTime.Now;
editmodel.LASTUPDATEDBY = Session["UserId"].ToString();
using (Entities db = new Entities(Session["Connection"] as EntityConnection)) {
    db.Entry(editmodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I think that I have tried this before. but yes it could help someone

Comment: I would like to clarify that adding .AsNoTracking() tells Entity Framework to stop tracking changes on the entity. If you do this, your entities should only be used in a "read-only" context, like displaying .Name in a WebForm as a title is fine. Using the entity in a form where it's data can be changed and saved is not.